# Are Netty's WebSocket messages been compressed?

Tags: java, websocket, netty

I'm developing a WebSocket server using Netty 4.0.21Final.

Before using Netty, I was sending data via socket directly and, now, I'm still doing the compression of the data by my self.

But, when looking closely at the HTTP Headers of my test client on Chrome browser, I saw this:

```
Request URL:ws://127.0.0.1:8089/echo
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:127.0.0.1:8089
Origin:null
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
Sec-WebSocket-Key:U0CPp11Bhqxp2lffj4tebw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:0vvWjhf27ScZauqx+jSfm/Xsuho=
Upgrade:websocket
```

The **permessage-deflate** on the Extensions section means that my messages are been compressed?

So, to try to answer this, I used a software called Wireshark and, when looking at the messages I could see that It was not compressed at all, they were all in plain text.

So, what do I must do to Netty really compress the messages for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression support was just added yesterday. So it is not included in any release yet:

https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/282d6e73b82ec943a739201f7be1985c45ef032b

Comment: Very appreciated for the quick answer. Hope that this feature doesn't take too long to be released.. Thanks again.